# How do I get the size of my Rich Text Field?

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I can get the size of the attachments using @Attachmentlength(), or Using NotesEmbeddedObject Class.

But I am facing a peculiar problem. If I copy and paste a screen shot, or copy and paste an image into a NotesRichText field then I could not retrieve the size of the field. Because these image is not fetched by embedded objects. NotesItem.ValuesLength does return the internal storage. I do not know what is it? :D. But surely it is not the size of that field. It is possible to get the size from the DXLExporter and NotesStream. But if I attach the pdf file then it is throwing error.

Simply say, I want to get the size of a rich text field.

Comment: If you are using Notes 8.5.1 or above, you could try the NotesDocument.ConvertToMIME method and then use the NotesMime classes to parse through and find the embedded graphic, but that probably converts it from Notes bitmap format to a standard format so the size is likely going to be different.  I think the only way to get the actual size would be to use the C API to parse through the rich text field's CD records.  Or perhaps the MIDAS Rich Text API can get you the info, but you would need a license for it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using 6.5.1 :(. But your's solution is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you copy your richtext item to newly created document and check size of whole document? I think that is quite simple and easy solution (and will be not a problem with access as we do not need to save document). Then you do not need to care about different kind of data into richtext field.

```
...
Set rtitem = doc.Getfirstitem("body")
Dim newdoc As New NotesDocument(db)
Call rtitem.Copyitemtodocument(newdoc, "body")
print newdoc.Size
```